# C++How do I connect a function to the program?

Tags: c++, function, numbers

I'm a beginner,in C++ and I wanted to do a program that finds the biggest of 3 numbers. Since I can't define the function that finds that in the main how do I do it without using classes? Thank you for your time!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int maximum(int x, int y, int z);

int main()
{
    int x,y,z;
    int max=y;
    int min=x;

    cout<<"Enter 3 numbers to find out which one is bigger. First: ";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Second: ";
    cin>>y;
    cout<<"Third: ";
    cin>>z;
    cout<<"Biggest is: "<<max<<endl;

    cout<<"Earliest time to meet is: "<<max<<endl;

    return 0;
}

//thats the function that checks the biggest number
int maximum (int x, int y, int z)
{
    int max = x;

    if (y > max) {
        max = y;
    }
    if (z > max) {
        max = z;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: you mean something like cout<<"Biggest is: "<<maximum(x,y,z)<<endl; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the maximum function from main() function. Simple.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int maximum(int x, int y, int z);

int main()
{
int x,y,z;

cout<<"Enter 3 numbers to find out which one is bigger. First: ";
cin>>x;
cout<<"Second: ";
cin>>y;
cout<<"Third: ";
cin>>z;
cout<<"Biggest is: "<< maximum (x, y, z) << endl;

return 0;
}

//thats the function that checks the biggest number
int maximum (int x, int y, int z) 
{
int max = x;

if (y > max) {
    max = y;
}
if (z > max) {
    max = z;
}

return max;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a [call to your function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_call), like

```
 max = maximum(x,y,z);
```

before displaying it

```
 cout<<"Biggest is: "<<max<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int maximum(int x, int y, int z);

int main()
{
   int x,y,z;
   // get values x, y, and z from user input
   int max = maximum(x, y, z);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: No, it is not useful to move the definition of the `maximum` function (which the OP has defined after his `main`)

Comment: Fair enough, didn't understand exact problem.